# Can not find symbol variable log

Tags: intellij-idea, annotations, symbols, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

IDEA2020.3Community
java1.8

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable log
```

- Enable annotation processing---check
- lombok plugin(newest 0.32-EAP)---check
- maven/gradle dependencies(`providedCompile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.16'`)---check
- Invalidate caches and restart---tried many times
  **no error/warning displayed, only if me building the project these errors pop up on build output**
  Why is this happening?

Comment: Do you face the same issue if you build using Maven/Gradle from command line outside IDE?

Comment: nope, maven/gradle build works fine even inside IDE, I'm facing the issue after press build project(ctrl + f9) button

Comment: Is it possible to share sample project example?

Comment: just using IDEA2020.3 creat a project whit maven or gradle and try use lombok, hardly work for me.

Comment: https://gitee.com/elunez/eladmin.git 
you can clone this open source project and built it to diecover the error

Comment: Looks like some issue with Lombok plugin - it works fine in Ultimate editon with bundled plugin.

Comment: i heard that IDEA2020.3 both cummunity and ultimate edition supposed to have the embedded lombok, but there is something wrong with cummunity edition

Comment: Yes, there was some issue with integrating plugin to Community edition. probably we need to wait for 2020.3.1 release.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `mvn compile` solved my problem.